# Memory leaking issue in Objective c App

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my iOS app ARC is disabled. I find some memory leak issues in my code when i inspect my code using instrument tool, it is described bellow.

Obj1 is a an object that declared in the .h file (its type is `classA`).

I set the value of `Obj1` in .m file using the code:

```
self.Obj1 = [[classA alloc]init];
```

I release `Obj1` in the dealloc method.

this code works fine. but shows a memory leak issue.

How can i avoid this memory leak issue.??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you make a property retain Obj1 means increment by 1 then after you alloc this object by increment 1, so it's value retain 2.

Use below code:

```
ClassA *objC = [[classA alloc]init];
self.Obj1 = objC;
[objC release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
self.Obj1 = [[[classA alloc]init]autorelease];
```

Dealloc will only be called when the view is not in use or unload.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSZombieEnabled macros for handling work with released objects all objects (even released) will have at least 1 retain count and tools will show all object as "leaking". Just turn off this macro when you work with memory leaks.
See technote for references:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to handle this :

First,

```
self.Obj1 = [[[classA alloc]init]autorelease];
```

Second,

```
Obj1 = [[classA alloc]init];
...
// use self.Obj1 in the code
...
[Obj1 release];
```

Third,

```
self.Obj1 = [[classA alloc]init];
...
[self.Obj1 release];
```

Use any one out of these.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove `self.`, just `Obj1 = [[classA alloc]init];`.
Because when you call `self.`,you retain the object again.So after `self.Obj1 = [[classA alloc]init];`,object retain count is 2.